# Is there a group theoretic proof that $(\mathbf Z/(p))^\times$ is cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, soft-question, cyclic-groups

**Theorem:** The group $(\mathbf Z/(p))^\times$ is cyclic for any prime $p$.

---

Most proofs make use of the fact that for $r\geq 1$, there are at most $r$ solutions to the equation $x^r=1$ in $\mathbf Z/(p)$, a result which doesn't seem — understandably — to have any group theoretic proofs.

K. Conrad gives ten different proofs — and hints at some others — in his paper [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicmodp.pdf). The first six make use of the previously mentioned fact, while the seventh proof makes extensive use of cyclotomic polynomials and is thus still not group-theoretic.

I was also able to find a linear algebra based proof in the second chapter of *Teoría Elemental de Grupos* by Emilio Bujalance García, but still, no group theoretic proof to be found.

Comment: Given that you are looking at the group of units of a ring, what makes you believe that you can find a purely group theoretic proof? You are dealing with a *ring* and with properties of *primes*, after all...

Comment: If there were one, I'd have included it. :)

Comment: More seriously, the unit group of $\mathbf Z/(m)$ is generally not cyclic, so proving it is when $m$ is a prime number (or an odd prime power) will need to use *something* that distinguishes those choices of $m$ from others, and a very basic one is that $\mathbf Z/(p)$ is a field, which is not a purely group-theoretic issue.

Comment: @KCd ... or twice an odd prime power...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yeah, or 4 also.

Comment: I agree with the previous comments, but maybe we can give a more "group-theoretic flavour" to the question if we ask: "Why is the automorphism group of a simple abelian group cyclic?"

Comment: @CaptainLama I agree, the question can be phrased very naturally group theoretically. Another (similar) way: why is the automorphism group of a group of prime order cyclic?

Comment: @CaptainLama, I think your point is precisely what I had in mind when trying with this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4222662/943729

Comment: I just wanted to say that the linked paper by @KCd is great!

Comment: I added a version of the linear algebra proof to the end of my document, so now it has 8 proofs, but the version I chose is based on the one in Fedor Petrov's answer to an MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic).

Comment: Group Theory and number theory have alot of overlap.   I find it hard to separate them out sometimes.

Comment: I've now add Matt Baker's $p$-adic proof, so now it has 9 proofs.

Comment: The proof using the fact that $x^r-1$ has only at most $r$ solutions seems pretty group-theoretic to me....you are given a group of order $p-1$ and are told it is abelian and that for any $r$, there are at most $r$ elements giving $x^r=e$. How much more group-theoretic can a proof possibly be.

Comment: To answer the question in @verret 's comment: because every $\psi\in Aut(\mathbb Z_p)$ is given by $\psi([0])=[0]$ and $\psi([i])=[\sigma(i)]$ (for $i=1,\dots,p-1$) where $\sigma\in S_{p-1}$ is of the form: $\sigma=(C)(i_2C)\dots(i_dC)$, being $$(C)=(1,\sigma(1),\sigma(1)^2,\dots,\sigma(1)^{\frac{p-1}{d}-1})$$ for some divisor $d$ of $p-1$, with $$1+\sigma(1)+\sigma(1)^2+\dots+\sigma(1)^{\frac{p-1}{d}-1}\equiv_p 0$$ Then the usual counting argument filtered by $d$ would follow.